# :not selector doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have this:

```css
b:not(.alert-danger) {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <h3><b>text</b></h3>
</div>

<h3><b>text2</b></h3>
```

The thing is that the alert (text) gets white and I don't understand what's happening. text2 also gets white but that's ok.

I just want to make effect on text2, not text1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
:not(.alert-danger) > h3 {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <h3><b>text</b></h3>
</div>
<h3><b>text2</b></h3>
```

Your selector:

```
b:not(.alert-danger) { color: #fff; }
```

...is saying:

> Target `b` elements unless they have a class of `alert-danger`.

This doesn't match your HTML structure. Plus you can't have a child matching on a parent, because that's not how CSS works.

The revised selector is saying:

> Target `h3` elements that are children of any element, unless that parent has a class of `alert-danger`.

You can also target the `b` if you prefer:

```
:not(.alert-danger) b { color: #fff }
```